# Administer simplenews subscriptions with views

Tags: 7, views, emails

In simplenews the default path to manage the subscriptions to newsletters is: admin/people/simplenews. The problem with that page is that it doesn't, for example, have any columns that would allow you to see when the subscription was added or even select all the subscriptions and perform actions on them (a feature that is available by default in vbo).

My question is the following:

Is there any way to make the specific page available for further configuration through Views so that I can add extra fields/features to it? What I'm looking for is basically something like [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) but for the simplenews interface.

Comment: I just tested the direct access to `admin/people/simplenews` for a non-admin. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for 2016 and Drupal 7.  Simplenews module does now include bulk operations.  Simplenews has Views integration built in.  It does not come with a pre-defined view, so you have to create one.

Here is an export of a view that shows when the subscriber was added and by what means.  However Simplenews does not current provide VBO integration to allow a bulk action.

```
  $view = new view();
  $view->name = 'newsletter_subscriptions';
  $view->description = '';
  $view->tag = 'default';
  $view->base_table = 'simplenews_subscription';
  $view->human_name = 'Newsletter subscriptions';
  $view->core = 7;
  $view->api_version = '3.0';
  $view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

  /* Display: Master */
  $handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
  $handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
  $handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
  $handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
  $handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
  $handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
  $handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
  $handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
  $handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
  $handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
    'mail' => 'mail',
    'name' => 'name',
    'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
    'activated' => 'activated',
    'source' => 'source',
    'status' => 'status',
    );
  $handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = 'mail';
  $handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
    'mail' => array(
      'sortable' => 1,
      'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
      'align' => '',
      'separator' => '',
      'empty_column' => 0,
      ),
    'name' => array(
      'sortable' => 1,
      'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
      'align' => '',
      'separator' => '',
      'empty_column' => 0,
      ),
    'timestamp' => array(
      'sortable' => 1,
      'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
      'align' => '',
      'separator' => '',
      'empty_column' => 0,
      ),
    'activated' => array(
      'sortable' => 1,
      'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
      'align' => '',
      'separator' => '',
      'empty_column' => 0,
      ),
    'source' => array(
      'sortable' => 1,
      'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
      'align' => '',
      'separator' => '',
      'empty_column' => 0,
      ),
    'status' => array(
      'sortable' => 1,
      'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
      'align' => '',
      'separator' => '',
      'empty_column' => 0,
      ),
    );
  /* Relationship: Simplenews subscription: Subscriber ID */
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['snid']['id'] = 'snid';
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['snid']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscription';
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['snid']['field'] = 'snid';
  /* Relationship: Simplenews subscription: Term ID */
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['tid']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscription';
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['tid']['label'] = 'Newsletter';
  /* Field: Simplenews subscriber: Subscriber */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscriber';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'snid';
  /* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Newsletter';
  /* Field: Simplenews subscription: Timestamp */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscription';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'short';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
  /* Field: Simplenews subscription: Source */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['source']['id'] = 'source';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['source']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscription';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['source']['field'] = 'source';
  /* Field: Simplenews subscriber: Activated */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['activated']['id'] = 'activated';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['activated']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscriber';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['activated']['field'] = 'activated';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['activated']['relationship'] = 'snid';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['activated']['type'] = 'unicode-yes-no';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['activated']['not'] = 0;
  /* Field: Simplenews subscription: Status */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscription';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['type'] = 'unicode-yes-no';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['not'] = 0;
  /* Filter criterion: Simplenews subscriber: Subscriber */
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscriber';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['relationship'] = 'snid';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['operator'] = 'contains';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['group'] = 1;
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['exposed'] = TRUE;
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'mail_op';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['label'] = 'Subscriber';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['operator'] = 'mail_op';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['identifier'] = 'mail';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
    2 => '2',
    1 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    );
  /* Filter criterion: Taxonomy term: Term */
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['relationship'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['group'] = 1;
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'tid_op';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['expose']['label'] = 'Newsletter';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['expose']['operator'] = 'tid_op';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'tid';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
    2 => '2',
    1 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    );
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['type'] = 'select';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['tid']['vocabulary'] = 'newsletter';
  /* Filter criterion: Simplenews subscriber: Activated */
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['id'] = 'activated';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['table'] = 'simplenews_subscriber';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['field'] = 'activated';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['relationship'] = 'snid';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['group'] = 1;
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['exposed'] = TRUE;
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['expose']['operator_id'] = '';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['expose']['label'] = 'Activated';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['expose']['operator'] = 'activated_op';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['expose']['identifier'] = 'activated';
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['activated']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
    2 => '2',
    1 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    );

  /* Display: Page */
  $handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
  $handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'newsletter-subscriptions';
  $handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
  $handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Newlsetter subscriptions';
  $handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
  $handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
  $handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
```